# How to make use of an M2 PCIe card UART interface?

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I have a motherboard (`AIMB-218`) with an M2 E key slot and according to the documentation of the said motherboard the M2 slot supports UART.

I am trying to use a wireless module (Wi-Fi + Bluetooth), which has a UART interface for controlling the Bluetooth adapter. Its documentation says that the Wi-Fi interface works using the PCIe bus and the Bluetooth uses UART interface.

I have booted a Linux Ubuntu on this system, but the UART interface does not show up in the /dev folder (there are only few `ttyS*` entries which correspond to serial ports present on the motherboard) nor the Bluetooth controller appears in the system in any other way - the `bluetoothctl` does not list any HCI devices.

The wireless module's chip is `88W8997` and the manufacturer claims it is supported by the Linux kernel.

My question is: How to make use of the UART interface of the card connected to the M2 slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make use of the M.2's UART interface, this interface needs to be implemented on the motherboard's M.2 slot.

According to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying) the M.2 E key slot supports the following interfaces:

> 2 of PCIe ×1, USB 2.0, I2C, SDIO, UART, PCM and CNVi

So, the UART interface will work as long as it is implemented on the interface by the motherboard's manufacturer and if it is not implemented then there is no way to make use of it.

The information regarding whether it is implemented or not could be found in the board's manual or confirmed with the board's manufacturer.

Comment: Assuming that the motherboard has an M.2 slot properly implementing UART, are there M.2 E key breakout cards that would allow easy access to this interface?

Comment: @ChristopherPelloux, I don't know. I personally never encountered such cards.